# Twig url() function returns CP path when called from plugin

Tags: templating, plugins, control-panel

I'm using [Postmaster](https://github.com/objectivehtml/Postmaster-for-Craft-CMS) plugin to handle my e-mails using a custom service for SendGrid. In my templates I use Twig's `url()` function to create my URLs.

When they are sent by Postmaster, `craft->template->render()` method creates a Control Panel url instead of a normal front-end URL. Which results in URL's not found when clicked in the e-mail.

Is this normal behaviour when the `render()` method is called from the control panel? Or can I override this in Twig templating maybe? The [Craft docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/functions#url) don't mention it.

In the meantime I can create my URL's using {{ siteUrl }}, but I'm wondering if I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right, `url()` (and [UrlHelper::getUrl()](https://craftcms.com/classreference/helpers/UrlHelper#getUrl-detail), which `url()` maps to) will create a URL to either a front-end page or a CP page, depending on where it is being called from.

If you want to get a front-end URL from a CP request, you can use `siteUrl()` instead. (You can also get a CP URL from a front-end request via `cpUrl()`.)

Comment: Nice! Didn't know that, works perfectly. Thanks Brandon!